# "/bin/sh": command not found, but only on second build step

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm attempting to create a Dockerfile for a tool called "diesel-cli". Diesel is an ORM and Query Builder for Rustlang, and this is their own CLI tool. I want to set it up in Docker, as it makes sense to have the DB CLI tool Dockerized if the DB is too. The tool itself isn't important, however.

I'm having a few issues with actually executing the tool in my preferred end environment (Alpine Linux), with the error being: `/bin/sh: diesel: not found`.

As you can see from the Dockefile below, the latest Rust Docker image is used to install the tool and retrieve the executable. The executable is then transferred to an Alpine image, which is to be the final environment, as that saves greatly on the image size. However, that causes the error mentioned above.

This error does not present itself if I were to just skip the Alpine stage altogether, though. Assuming I comment out the `FROM` and the `COPY`, there are no issues at all. I can build and call the tool as expected. But the Rust image is nearly 2GB, not to mention contains unneeded dependencies, which is undesirable.

Using a `RUN ls /bin/` I can confirm the executable is transferred to the new environment. To ensure both images are running the command the same way, I used `docker ps -l` from the host to confirm both use `/bin/sh -c diesel`, so that did not explain it either.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:latest as builder

RUN cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres

FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/diesel /bin/diesel

ENV DATABASE_URL postgres://tempest_api:admin@postgres:5432/tempest

CMD diesel
```

The only error message I receive is the rather unhelpful `/bin/sh: diesel: not found`. After building and running, the goal is to make the command accessible with a simple `docker run diesel ...` (assuming the image is tagged as 'diesel').

Answer (score 0):

As I looked here: [Rust Docker tutorial](https://shaneutt.com/blog/rust-fast-small-docker-image-builds/) you are suffering the described error of missing libraries.

Run `docker run --rm -it myapp ldd /bin/diesel` to see which are missing and then follow their directions to copy them in your second build step.

I ran the command and got:

```
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f1c5b5fe000)
Error loading shared library libpq.so.5: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/diesel)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f1c5b5fe000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f1c5b5fe000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f1c5b5fe000)
Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/diesel)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f1c5b5fe000)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/diesel)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f1c5b5fe000)
```

That's where your `not found` originates.

Comment: The error comes when I try to run the docker image, so when the `CMD` is ran. Changing the command to `/bin/diesel` has no effect. Rust:latest is not based on Alpine, nor does it need to be. As I said in my post, Alpine is used to have a minuscule final image. A Rust install will be 1.5GB+. Alpine wouldn't exactly make sense.

Comment: What happens when you run a shell within the container via `docker exec -it diesel /bin/sh` and from there run the CLI? I asked about alpine because the might be a problem with libraries been different in the alpine and rust images.

Comment: The same thing happes. `/bin/sh: diesel: not found`. There shouldn't be an issue, as far as I can tell. Even if there were a problem with the libraries, that would cause issues with the executable finishing. Here, the executable isn't even being ran, as it cannot be found, evidently.

Comment: As far as the comment on the brackets, it makes no difference for CMD, as far as I am aware. No practical effect is seen if I change it, and the documentation doesn't specify a difference.

Comment: I installed those libraries, and that solved nothing. Same issue persists. That tutorial also seems rather irrelevant, as I'm not building any Rust projects with this. Just installing a binary.

Comment: But it perhaps is a problem, when compiling a binary on one Linux and then running it on another. What is your source for your two stage build to work in the first place? I even tried installing rust within the alpine container and running the build and the compilation failed. So my educated guess is alpine missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Dockerfile like this:

```
CMD ["/bin/diesel","diesel"]
```